# property about transient and recurrent states of a Markov chain

Tags: probability, solution-verification

From [here](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter11/11_2_4_classification_of_states.php), we know that given a Markoc chain ans a state $i$, $i$ is transient if
$$ P(X_n = i, \text{ for some } n \geq 1 |X_0 =i) <1$$

Consider the following statements:

1. States in a class of a finite Markov chain is either all transient or all recurrent.
2. There is no finite Markov chain in which all states are transients.
3. All states of a finite irreducible Markov chain are recurrent.

So here is my attempt to prove the claims:

1. Suppose that state $i$ is transient and state $i$ and state $j$ belong to the same class in a Markov chain, then there exist $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $P^n(j,i)>0$ and there is a state $m$ where $m$ is accessible from $i$ but $i$ is not accessible from $m$. But then $m$ is accessible from $j$ via $i$ but $j$ is not accessible via $m$ or else $i$ would have been accessible from $m$.
2. Suppose there is a Markov chain where all of its states are transient, then given a initial distribution of being at any given states, the probability that we are at any given states after several time step tends to $0$. But this cannot be possible as the probability at any given state must sum up to one.(So here I think the claim is not rigorous, so any comment would be appreciated.)
3. A Markov chain is irreducible if it has only one class. Hence all states are reachable from all states. Therefore, the probability that a state comes back to itself is not null.

Comment: I would avoid using the word "possible", as events with $0$ probability are still "possible". For example, in a simple random walk, it is "possible" we never go back to the origin after leaving it, but we still say that $0$ is a recurrent state.

Comment: Your reasoning for $3$ is messy and not correct. Instead, it is as simple as irreducible=one class, statement 1 implies all states are transient or recurrent, statement 2 says they can't all be transient.

Comment: I've removed my comments claiming that the statements are invalid, as you have edited them to be correct. This doesn't change the fact that the proofs are not good, so I am currently writing an answer to provide acceptable proofs.

Comment: Yes sir please , I was also trying to look for more rigorous proof hehe

Comment: I'm only beginning to read about the notes also. Please forgive my unintuitive understanding of the subject

Comment: *" a state of a Markov chain is transient if after leaving the state, we can never go back again"* this is innacurate and problematic on multiple levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left some comments regarding my impressions of your proofs, so here's how I would do the proofs myself.

> States in a class of a Markov Chain are either all recurrent or transient.

Suppose state $i$ and $j$ communicate, and state $i$ is recurrent. Let $p=P_n(i,j)>0$. Thus, the expected number of visits to $j$ is at least $p$ times the expected number of visits to $i$, which is infinite. Hence, the expected number of visits to $j$ is infinite, hence it is recurrent. If $i$ is transient, $j$ can't be recurrent, since by the previous argument, that would imply $i$ is recurrent.

> There is no finite Markov chain in which all states are transient.

By the pigeonhole principle, there is at least one state that will be reached infinitely many times. In other words, if $M$ is a Markov chain with states $[k]=\{1,\ldots, k\}$, if $A_i$ for $i\in[k]$ represents the event that state $i$ is reached infinitely many times, then by inclusion exclusion $$1=P(A_1\cup\ldots\cup A_k)=P(A_1)+P(A_2)+\ldots+P(A_k)-P(A_1\cap A_2)-\ldots+P(A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3)+\ldots\pm\ldots\pm P(A_1\cap A_2\cap\ldots\cap A_k)$$But all of the terms on the right side of the equation are $0$ if each state is transient. This is a contradiction.

> All states of a finite irreducible Markov chain are recurrent.

As irreducible Markov chains have one class, statement $1$ implies all states are either transient or recurrent. But statement $2$ implies that all states are not transient. Hence, they are all recurrent.